# extract address to city,state,country,postcode using jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Currenty, I'm using the following code to get the  Google Places Autocomplete TextBox without using Google Maps.I need to extract this address component to city,state ,postcode,country in place_changed event
I am using this code to get location

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('MainContent_txtpostcode'));

            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();

            });
        });
```

for example if our location is Shelgate Road, London SW11 1BD, United Kingdom.I want to extract address as Road Name:Shelgate Road,City:London Post Code:SW11 1BD Country:United Kingdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It's very simple:

```
<input type="text" id="mapLocation" />
<div id="data"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#mapLocation")[0]);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      $('#data').html('<div>Postal Code: '+place.address_components[0].long_name+'</div><div>Road Name:'+place.address_components[1].long_name+'</div><div>City:'+place.address_components[2].long_name+'</div><div>Country:'+place.address_components[2].long_name+'</div>');
            console.log(place.address_components);
        });
});
</script>
```

[Demo of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/xj2d77be/6/)

Answer (score 0):

*places.getPlace().address_components* has collection of address-strings which can be then formatted to our choice.

Please see a sample below:

```
var processAddressString = function(place) {
   var addressString = ''; 
   place.map(function(obj) {
       addressString += obj.long_name;
   });
   return addressString;
}

var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('MainContent_txtpostcode'));
google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = places.getPlace().address_components;
    //'place' now has array of objects where each is city,state ,postcode,country etc. 
    //You now need to loop through this and extract the short_name/long_name and form the required string
    console.log('Address is : ', processAddressString(place);)
});
```